# Ember.getOwner for service lookup in integration tests

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have some Ember integration tests where I need to access the store.  I have been using:

`Ember.getOwner(this).lookup("service:store");`

This works fine but I was wondering if there is a better way to get at the store in integration tests.  In ember unit tests, using ember-qunit and `moduleForModel`, the store can be accessed easily with:

```
this.store();
```

The current [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/testing-components/) around integration testing mention stubbing and registering services, but there is no explicit mention of the accessing the store.

What is the proper way to access and interact with the store in the context of an integration test with model dependencies?

Comment: Why do you need the actual store? Do you need to make actual HTTP calls in your tests? That seems prone to failure.

Comment: @locks No http call. Just calling store.createRecord.

Comment: This is one of the many frustrating "assumptions" that Ember made, given how vital `store.createRecord` is for testing basically ANY component that relies on DS models... Especially frustrating given that `Ember.getOwner` isn't available prior to 2.3ish

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you stub the store too.

```
  subject.store = {
    createRecord = function() {}
  }
```

You'll test the complete interaction in your acceptance tests.